# Open the link in new window in crystal report

Tags: sql-server-2008, crystal-reports, sql-server-2008-r2, crystal-reports-xi

I have crystal report. There is the column containing the hyperlink. I want whenever click that link that page should open in new window. All this should be done in crystal reports.

Can I get any help?

Comment: what you say as "that page" ?? whether it is a crystal report page, html page or any other web page?

Comment: That page means the destination page which is on internet....                This is what I actually want...... there is the field on the report which is the hyperlink.....now when i click that link, webpage should open in new window

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Field contains a URL and if you want to make that URL as hyperlink in crystal report, it can be done.
Consider the following sample report, which contains search engine's names and their links
[image]

Now your requirement is to open Google by clicking `www.google.com`. 
**Right Click** the field which you want to make Hyperlink, and select **Format Field**.
You will get the Format Editor as like the following image. Select **Hyperlink** tab and select **Hyperlink Type** as ***A Website on the Internet***
Select the formula field in **Hyperlink Information** and use your column which has URL in it and save formula. Now press OK and Preview the report.
[image]
You could see the link opens when you press the Field. You can also change the font color of the field to show that is a LINK.

**EDIT**
`{link}+'?sWindow=New'`
Using '?sWindow=New' after your link may open your link new tab
Try this and get back with your results !

Comment: Yes I have done this... But I want this link to be open in new window or new tab. I am using crystal reports for visual studio 2010, So there is no hyperlinktarget option. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your column have Hyperlink, right? then use that column in formula. For each row the hyperlink will be taken from your column and that would be ur destination URL. 
In which format your hyperlink is avail in your column ?

Comment: hyperlink is ther interneet address and it already used in formula. As in now hyperlink is opened in same window but i wantthis link to be opened in the new window. Is there any settings to be done for this?

Comment: Hey It still opens in the same window. I tried the same as u told:    "www.google.com" & '?sWindow=New'

Comment: `www.google.com+'?sWindow=New'` have you tried the same syntax??

Comment: hey .... have u got any other solution for this.... I m stuck in this since long time

Comment: Sorry frnd, even I am trying, but i couldnt get any. Get me some time !

Comment: hey bro.. i got the solution....... its was in .net code we have to insert hyperlink="_target"

Comment: The {link}+'?sWindow=New' solution will work if your URL does not have any other parameters in the URL. In situations where you have other parameters, you would replace the ? with an & (ampersand). The ? (question mark) is only valid if this is the first dynamic parameter in the URL.

Comment: @user1599392: How you do that i .net code? I am struggling since many days but not found any solution.. can you help?

Answer (score 3):

The report viewer has a property called HyperlinkTarget. Set it to "_blank" to open in a new window.

```
<CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="crvReportView" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" HyperlinkTarget="_blank" />
```

Answer (score 1):

add a target= "_blank" to your html  tag i.e.:

```
<a href="default.asp" target = "_blank">HTML Tutorial</a>
```

Comment: That page means the destination page which is on internet....                This is what I actually want...... there is the field on the report which is the hyperlink.....now when i click that link, webpage should open in new window

Comment: Where I can type this code givesn by you in the crystal reports