# Open Popup from hyperlink that's been displayed in a crystal report

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink, crystal-reports

I am unable to make the hyperlinks in a crystal report open up in a new window. They always directs the report to another page. How do I make them into pop-ups? Need to show some detail info as a popup when user'll click on a hyperlink so that they can close it and see the main report without having to reload it.
Using ASP.NET(C#) with SQL SERVER 2012
Thanks

I'm attaching a sample image to explain the scenario a bit more. The image below is a part of my report where the blue link inside the red box is a hyperlink. On click event of that hyperlink I want to open a pop up window(.aspx).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the report it self right click on your field to be hyperlink >> Format Object >> change the tab to hyperlink >> you can choose if your page is a file or a website on the internet >> if you are selecting a file you have to browse the location mostly it will be on your project, or if you are selecting a website on the internet you have to provide the URL e.g
 HTTP//
localhost:60469/Project1/Reports/ReportViewer.aspx?ReportId=6"

in your case insert the popup path
add this to your formula to open in a new tab

{YourField}+'?sWindow=New'

also you can add formula to set your invoice number to retrieve certain data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...but I think this is not what I'm looking for. I've explained my question a bit more.

Comment: @ZoeHime you need it inside the report?? after clicking on the link you want to open the popup with certain information for each row??

Comment: but this way it opens the page in the same tab...I want it to be opened in a new tab or as a popup window.

Comment: actually I've tried this as well...my URL is kinda like this: ToText({?URL})+"/Report/ServiceReport.aspx?ReportName=InvoiceFinal&JobID="+ToText({tblJobVehicleInformation.JobID},0,"")+"&Invoiceno="+ToText({tblJobVehicleInformation.InvoiceNo},0,"")+"&PaymentType="+{tblJobVehicleInformation.PaymentType}+"&sWindow=New"+""

Comment: is it not working becausee I've used parameters along with the url?

Comment: I simply tried this just to check where the problem is: "../service/CustomerAppoinment.aspx?sWindow=New"......it opens the page in the same tab. Am I missing something or is there really some problem? Help is much appreciated.

Comment: @ZoeHime http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636429/open-the-link-in-new-window-in-crystal-report